# Is search in database is always accurate?

Tags: database, algorithm, search, information-retrieval

Is search in database is always accurate ?

From our IR course exam: What is the difference between database management and information retrieval system !

The expected Answer: Database is structured data and accuracy is 100%. IR is unstructured and not always accurate.

Comment: Pretty bogus question (I mean, the exam question, not yours, although there is no real way to answer that one either).

Answer (score 0):

First, let me answer your question:

> Is search in database is always accurate ?

No. One good example is [bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). Bloom filters represent *sets*, and you can do the following operations on them<sup>1</sup>:

- add - adds an element
- isInSet - checks if a given element is in the set or not.

The thing is, bloom filters are probabalistic data structures. They have False Positives (you ask is an element there? The answer should be "No", but the algorithm yields "Yes" with some small probability)

Bloom Filters are structured, and do not always return the correct answer, and one might choose to implement a DB upon them in some situations.

That said, what I think the question intent was to ask about Relational DB, such as SQL. In SQL - you know exactly what you search for, and the data is structured in tables that can be searched to get an exact answer - does it contain a certain field - or not? Such DB is usually designed for a specific task that you can always answer correctly, and there is a very specific way you can insert data to your DB. Free search on the other hand does not have such luxury. Anyone can insert data however he wishes in the form of a document, and your system has to process it, including all the noise from various writers. This results in heuristics solutions that sometimes lead to mistakes.

---

(1) There are extensions of bloom filters that also allow deletion (counting bloom filter), and adding union to unite two sets is pretty trivial in bloom filters.